# What does an S21 of 0dB mean?

Tags: impedance, vna

In a video titled [PDN Measurements with a VNA](https://ee-training.dk/power-integrity/pdn-measurement-with-a-network-analyzer.htm) Rolf Ostergaard shows how to transform the magnitude of the insertion loss S21 to an impedance value. This is the formula he uses:

$$
Z = 25\Omega \times 10^{\frac{S_{21}[dB]}{20}}
$$

Then, in the [comments](https://ee-training.dk/power-integrity/pdn-measurement-with-a-network-analyzer.htm#comment-871), someone asks why he uses \$25\Omega\$ when the port impedances are \$50\Omega\$. The author's response is:

> Try doing the math. Remember, 0dB means the receiver sees half the generator amplitude.

I don't get it:

**Why does 0 dB mean that the receiver sees half the generator amplitude?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why does 0 dB mean that the receiver sees half the generator amplitude?

Because this is the actual circuit:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fvJxrk.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

In order to **match the impedance** the generator will have a 50 Ohms output impedance and the load will also be 50 Ohms. Without that the coaxial cable will not be properly matched and you will get **signal reflections** which cause distortion.

This is an **ideal** system where S21 = 0 dB, consider that the **reference**. Any deviations from that will show as S21 not being zero dB.

Comment: I guess it all depends on what is meant by the term "generator output".  If I have a signal generator or vna who's output impedance is specified to be 50 ohms, and if I take that output to be the generator's output, then the receiver (load) would see the full generator's output voltage if S21 of the cable were 0 dB.

Comment: [Todd Hubing's Power Bus Decoupling on Multilayer Printed Circuit Boards](https://scholarsmine.mst.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=2210&context=ele_comeng_facwork) (p.161) made everything click into place for me together with your answer.